# KNOCKOUT JS: $root, $parent and $parents parameter in nested foreach giving me $data

Tags: knockout.js

I wrote nested foreach on my code

```
        <div class="row justify-content-center" data-bind="foreach: subCategoryList">
            <div class="row text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-3">
                <h5 class="text-uppercase text-warning" data-bind="text: 'Choose your ' + $data"></h5>
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: $root.ProductListBySubCategory($root, $data)-->
            <div class="col-sm-3 px-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img onerror="Util.ImagePlaceholder(this, 262, 262)" class="product-image img-fluid shadow rounded" data-bind="attr: { src: Util.ResolveUrlApi('/' + ImageSmall) }" />
                        <h5 class="text-center text-secondary mt-5" data-bind="text:Util.FormatCurrency(UnitPrice)"></h5>
                        <ul class="mt-3" data-bind="visible: !Util.IsEmpty(Description">
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <span data-bind="text: (!Util.IsEmpty(Description) ? Desciption : 'N/A')"></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn text-uppercase" data-bind="click: $root.ClickSubtractQuantity.bind($root)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 px-2">
                            <input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control text-center" />
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn text-uppercase" data-bind="click: $root.ClickAddQuantity.bind($root)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

I have trouble in `click: $root.ClickSubtractQuantity.bind($root)` and `click: $root.ClickAddQuantity.bind($root)` the parameter $root keeps passing record of `$root.ProductListBySubCategory($root, $data)` or rather `$data` and not my `viewModel`, anyone can help ? I need to access some variable in my viewmodel and update it.

Comment: Please share your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer from @Brother_Woodrow you can also specify a name for the current item in a `foreach` like this, that will help when the nesting is deep.

```
<div data-bind="foreach {data: subCategoryList, as: 'subCategory'}" />
  <!-- ko foreach: {data: $root.ProductListBySubCategory($root, subCategory), as: 'product'}-->
    <div data-bind="text: subCategory.name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: product.name"></div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter you pass to `bind` becomes the value `this` in the function, so in `ClickAddQuantity`, `this` should now refer to `$root`. The first parameter your handler will receive will indeed still be `$data` since that's KO's default behavior, unless you were to overwrite that: `click: $root.ClickSubtractQuantity.bind($root, $root)`. The *second* parameter you pass to the `bind` method becomes the *first* argument to the function.

It's much easier though to just copy the reference to `this` to a different variable like `self` or `vm`, so you have easy access to your viewmodel in every function.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.foo = '123';
    
    vm.myClickHandler = function (item) {
        // 'item' is the item that was clicked
        // 'vm' is the viewmodel ($root usually)
        // So you can now access 'vm.foo'
    }
}
```

Then you can just do away with the `bind` stuff.

Comment: thanks for this, but I have class ViewModel not function, more like type script i think ? and I got solutions that I think now that good, I put my `ViewModel` in variable outside, like this `Class ViewModel(){.....} var vm = new ViewModel` then bind it `ko.applyBindings(vm);` and I'm calling `vm` inside my class functions, that way, im able to use my ViewModel variables like `vm.foo`. lol